# Ruby on Rails Method Mocks in the Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock a method call to an outside API inside one of my rails controllers (in this case, Instagram.get_access_token) and I'm having some trouble.  As written, the code is still calling the real Instagram.get_access_token method.  How do I have the controller use my simple mock instead?

#### sessions_controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  require 'instagram'
  include ApplicationHelper

  def auth_callback
    response = Instagram.get_access_token(params[:code],
                                          redirect_uri: auth_callback_url)
    #<snipped extra code>
  end
end
```

#### sessions_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'ostruct'

describe SessionsController do
  describe "GET #auth_callback" do
    context "when there is an existing user" do
      let(:response) { OpenStruct.new(access_token: "good_access_token") }

      it "parses an access_token from the get response" do
        Instagram.should_receive(:get_access_token).and_return(response)

        #<snipped extra code>
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Instagram.stub(:get_access_token) { response }
```

Do you have the same result?

Comment: Yep, it's still calling the real Instagram.get_access_token (and thus giving me a Instagram::BadRequest response (instead of my simple struct).

Comment: That's weird. `stub` and `should_receive` should work. If you use a `before (:each)` block, do you have the same result?